# How to access the data in a char array by having it's address in C?

Tags: c, return-type

I am writing a system call function (in FreeBSD). As you may know the return type of such a function is an int which only indicates whether the syscall has been successful or not and the value which the caller has asked for is returned through setting:

```
td->td_retval[0]= my_requires_value;
```

where td is of type thread* and td_retval[0] is an int.

My problem is that my required value is a char []. How can I manage this? What should I set td->td_retval[0] as here in the syscall and how can I retrieve it back in the caller function?

I'm not very familiar with C and its pointers but I feel like this can be accomplished through using the right pointers and addresses.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you mean you need to convert a number stored as a string in a `char` array to an `int`?

Comment: No, I need the actual string (i.e. text) to be reachable/usable in the caller function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a string, your function should have an argument that is a pointer to a pre-allocated buffer in user space that will take the string (and another argument with the maximum size). The return value is only used to report errors, e.g. that the provided buffer is too small.

See [this](http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/how-to-create-a-system-call-for-freebsd-kernel/) example, it may help you to design your syscall.

Comment: Since this is a system call funtion, the arguments are fixed and I can not change it.

Comment: Do you intend to replace an existing call? Have you read the example I provided?